# iterating through rows of a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagrid, datarow

I am trying to extract values from a datagrid, by iterating through all the rows of the datagrid

```
    foreach (DataRow drv in PGIPortfolio.Items)
    {
    // DataRow row = drv.Row;

    string acname = drv["Portfolio"].ToString();
string paramt = drv["Par Amount"].ToString();
MessageBox.Show(acname);
```

}

But it is giving me an InvalidCastException at DataRow drv.
Could someone tell me what changes I should make so it works? 
The datagrid has a binding, and it is being populated by a stored procedure from ms sql 2008 database

Comment: Try this, change the foreach loop to read

    foreach (var drv in PGIPortfolio.Items)
    {
    }

and hover over drv.  What does Intellisense tell you?

Comment: Tried using var too.Doesn't work that way either

Answer (score 10):

Use a [DataGridRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.aspx) not a [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) they are a different objects

```
foreach (DataGridRow drv in PGIPortfolio.Items)
```

However it is not clear what Items is in this context. Assuming that PGIPortfolio is the DataGridView then your loop should be written as

```
foreach (DataGridRow drv in PGIPortfolio.Rows)
```

**EDIT**
I assumed that you was using the DataGridView control in WinForms, not the WPF DataGrid
In this case then the correct approach is to use the ItemsSource property.
Please try this code....

```
    var itemsSource = PGIPortfolio.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (itemsSource != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = PGIPortfolio.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (row != null) 
            {
               .....
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: PGIPortfolio is a datagrid, not a datagridview. So .Rows is not recognized

Comment: It says no definition for Rows and no extension method Rows accepting a first argument of type Datagrid.

Comment: You'll have to use PGIPortfolio.DataSource then and cast it to you what you want.  [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx) does not support .Items or even .Rows

Comment: I see you are still using the old control DataGrid, let me update the answer

Comment: thanks Steve, I am not getting the exception now, but dt is null. :(

Comment: How do you set the initial DataSource of the DataGrid (I mean how do you fill the grid)?

Comment: PGIPortfolio.ItemsSource = storedprocedure
 //I use the stored procedure to load data into the data grid

Comment: Could you edit your question adding the code used to fill the ItemsSource? I still cannot understand what datatype is present in your grid. (WPF Datagrid right?)

Answer (score -1):

`foreach(DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)`

Comment: DataGrid from WPF and DataGridView re two different things.