# Looping through the cells in a C# datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a `datagrid`, in which I am trying to loop through rows of a particular column to check the value in the cell and based on the value I would like to perform some formatting.

I am looping through the DG using following code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dgdPriceDropdown.VisibleRowCount;i++ )
                {
                    double temp=(Convert.ToDouble(dgdPriceDropdown[i,6]));
                    if (Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(dgdPriceDropdown[i,6]))==0.97)
                    {

                    }
                }
```

Now, I would like to apply background color to cell which has a value 97 after the decimal

**May I know a way to do this?**

Comment: Can't you use the Items property of DataGrid?

Comment: Well I do not see Item property within the DataGrid, It is a kind of User defined control with inherits from DataGrid control

Comment: You'll have to do some binding and then in your code behind make the changes before you show the user what you want to show

Comment: Updated the question to be more precise and included my code

Answer (score 1):

For iterating through rows of a datagrid, this link might be usefull 
[Iterating_Through_DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863531/iterating-through-rows-of-a-datagrid), for formatting the DataGrid, this project might be helpfull [DataGrid_Formatting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7995/DataGrid-Formatting)